# GZip Compression for SharePoint

Tags: 2013, performance, iis, gzip, compression

I have a site collection which needs to be compressed. So I followed [Code Project Article here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/242133/Making-the-most-out-of-IIS-compression-Part-conf).

For that I have enabled both of the compression in my **IIS** > **Compression** setings as below screen:

[image]

Now when I see the site in the network panel of developer tools, it doesn't show `content-encoding: gzip` for the home page which has the `mimeType` as `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Other than this `mimeType`, I was able to see the JS, CSS files are coming with response attribute of `content-encoding:gzip`. So I updated the `applicationHost.config` and added `mimeType` for `text/html; charset=utf-8`. See below config file:

[image]

Now my question is, is this the correct way to compress the site in `GZip` format?

Any other possible way for this?

How can I achieve the same without updating `applicationHost.config`? Can we do the same configuration in web application's `web.config` entry?

Thanks in advance.